# product description - WYSIWYG editor is not displayed

Tags: magento-1.7, product, catalog, admin

my WYSIWYG editor is not displayed in product description in the admin panel.

my sittings:
Catalog-->magnage attributes--> description --> Enable WYSIWYG = "yes"
system --> configuration --> Content Management --> Enable WYSIWYG Editor = "Enabled by Default"

has anyone any idea?

Comment: Do you get any js errors?

Comment: Does it mean you don't get `WYSIWYG Editor` button under description textarea?

Comment: nope :(, and also nothing in the log files

Comment: ya Tim, i dont get WYSIWYG Editor button under description textarea

Comment: Did you find a solution? Share it with us!

Answer (score 2):

## General

First, confirm that the areas shows *anywhere*. Regardless, this error is occurring due to an issue in one of two areas:

1. Incorrect/missing/superseded files
2. Incorrect/missing configuration

## 1. Incorrect/missing/superseded files

Diff a known-good copy of your version of Magento against yours. Correct any differences, restore files, and reset theme settings such that the "default" behavior *should* be in effect

## 2. Incorrect/missing configuration

You've confirmed that the configuration settings to display this button are set, but `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Helper_Form_Wysiwyg::getIsWysiwygEnabled()` checks if the  `Mage_Cms` module is active to display even the disabled version of the button. Check that.